# Class member fields not initialized when constructor is called in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

I am new to flutter. As a learning project i am building a quiz app. I am using Flutter riverpod for state management. Currently, there are three layers (model, repository, view) in my project. **quiz.model.dart** is connected to **quiz.repository.dart** and **quiz.repository.dart** is connected to **home.view.dart**. Whenever i call quiz repository it gives me error

```
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'question' has not been initialized.)
```

The link to the project repository is [here](https://github.com/shahabgohar/quiz_app). I have also created a new branch **error_fix** for this purpose. Kindly propose your changes in that branch. Any help will be appreciated as i have already spend a large amount of time on this. **Thank You!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the 'this' keyword in the 'Question' class constructor. You should change the code as in the examples below.

change

```dart
  Question({
    required category,
    required type,
    required difficulty,
    required question,
    required correctAnswer,
    required answers,
  });
```

to

```dart
  Question({
    required this.category,
    required this.type,
    required this.difficulty,
    required this.question,
    required this.correctAnswer,
    required this.answers,
  });
```